# How To send email using Adobe AIR?

Tags: air, adobe, sendmail

I have searched how to send e-mail using adobe air.. But i didn't find a good one. They only show for adobe flax... There some codes that included some library.

I don't understand how to use it.. Anybody could help?

Answer (score 2):

check out Thibault Imbert's [SMTP Mailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27).  the [download (latest version 0.9)](http://code.google.com/p/smtpmailer/downloads/list) includes source files, a library .swc and a sample application for Flash (with frame script).

### Update

here's the frame script that is included with the 0.9 release of SMTP Mailer:

```
import org.bytearray.smtp.mailer.SMTPMailer;
import org.bytearray.smtp.encoding.JPEGEncoder;
import org.bytearray.smtp.encoding.PNGEnc;
import org.bytearray.smtp.events.SMTPEvent;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.*;

// create the socket connection to any SMTP socket
// use your ISP SMTP

var myMailer:SMTPMailer = new SMTPMailer (smtp_txt.text, 25);

// register events
// event dispatched when mail is successfully sent
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_SENT, onMailSent);
// event dispatched when mail could not be sent
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.MAIL_ERROR, onMailError);
// event dispatched when SMTPMailer successfully connected to the SMTP server
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.CONNECTED, onConnected);
// event dispatched when SMTP server disconnected the client for different reasons
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.DISCONNECTED, onDisconnected);
// event dispatched when the client has authenticated successfully
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.AUTHENTICATED, onAuthSuccess);
// event dispatched when the client could not authenticate
myMailer.addEventListener(SMTPEvent.BAD_SEQUENCE, onAuthFailed);

// take the snapshot
var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData ( stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );

// encode as JPEG with quality 100
var myEncoder = new JPEGEncoder( 100 );

send_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

message_txt.text = "<img src='http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif'</img><br><b>Picture file attached ! :)</b>";

function onClick ( pEvt:MouseEvent )

{

    // replace this by any DisplayObject
    myBitmap.draw ( this );

    var myCapStream:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode ( myBitmap );

    // sends HTML email
    //myMailer.sendHTMLMail ( from_txt.text, to_txt.text, subject_txt.text, "<img src='http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif'</img><br><b>Picture from HTML :)</b>");

    // send HTML email with picture file attached
    myMailer.sendAttachedMail ( from_txt.text, to_txt.text, subject_txt.text, message_txt.text, myCapStream, "image.jpg");

}

function onAuthFailed ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void

{

    status_txt.htmlText = "Authentication Error";

}

function onAuthSuccess ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void

{

    status_txt.htmlText = "Authentication OK !";

}

function onConnected ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 

{

    status_txt.htmlText = "Connected : \n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}

function onMailSent ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ) 

{

    // when data available, read it
    status_txt.htmlText = "Mail sent :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}

function onMailError ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 

{

    status_txt.htmlText = "Error :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}

function onDisconnected ( pEvt:SMTPEvent ):void 

{

    status_txt.htmlText = "User disconnected :\n\n" + pEvt.result.message;
    status_txt.htmlText += "Code : \n\n" + pEvt.result.code;

}


function socketErrorHandler ( pEvt:IOErrorEvent ) 

{

    // when data available, read it
    status_txt.htmlText = "Connection error !";

}
```

Comment: sample for Adobe AIR please?? anybody have it?

Comment: ?  the package contains a frame script.

Comment: i'm assuming you don't have Flash and therefore don't have access to the sample, so i've posted the frame script in my updated answer.

Comment: dear TheDarkInI1978... I will explain my project. now i am buiding simple mail with air, jquery, and html.... i have tried for searching some codes send email, but i found for flash, flax... i know there is action script..but i confuse how to include it in my project... i call all function only with javascript(Jquery) function..how about it?.. and i have tried for including actionscript but it still errors?.. can you help me?

Comment: Hi TheDarkInI1978, i have tried your code using flash.. i change the smtp using gmail: smtp.gmail.com with port 587... it can be connected...but when i press send button, apllication error and show the status  'Error 1 :

250 mx.google.com at your service' if i press again status will be shown like this '530 5.7.0 Must issue a START TLS command first. r29sm1129096ybn.10'.. i know google must start TLS for sending email.. and my questions is how to start TLS with action script?

Code : 

250'... u